# How to redirect to another route after comparing global variable to local variable

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a component that takes in a global variable from my Provider class (I'm using context api to manage state) and compares it to a local variable. If the variables match, I want to render the DOM and if they don't match, I want to redirect to another route.

I've tried using the withContext hook in componentDidMount() to bring in the global variable to set up my conditional but that didn't work.  I also tried putting a conditional in the render method which worked until I tried using Redirect as my else statement. I also tried this.props.history.push in the else statement, but that also threw errors.

**app.js**

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Provider>
    <Header />
      <Switch>   

       //This is the component i'm working on
       <Route path='/test' component={test} /> 

       //This is the component I'm trying to redirect to
       <Route path='/error' component={errorPage} />

       <Route component = {PageNotFound} />
       </Switch>
  </Provider>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**/context/index.js**

```
class Provider extends Component {

  state = {
    globalID: ''
  };

 render(){
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value = {{
        data: this.state,
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  };
};
```

**test.js**
// this is what i'm working on but React is not liking that redirect tag

```
export default class UpdateCourse extends Component {
  state = {
    localID: ''
  }

  render()
   const ID = this.state.localID
   return (
    <div>
    <Consumer>
      {({data}) => (  
        {ID === data.globalID ?
         <React.Fragment>
          <div>
           <p>test</p>
          </div>
        : <Redirect to = '/error' />


// I omitted a lot but hopefully you get the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish
```

So basically, if globalID and localID are the same then I want to show the test component. If they are not the same I want to automatically redirect to the error route

Comment: Have you verified that (ID === data.globalID) is false?

Comment: Yes. I tested out the else statement without the Redirect to be sure.